# BigCommerce API - Can't create a new customer

Tags: php, bigcommerce

Checked out similar questions on Stackoverflow but, being a newbie to BC, still having real trouble with this one. Trying to create a new customer using Bigcommerce API (PHP).

I've been able to connect to my Bigcommerce store using API (PHP) and get data, for example, a list of customers. The code (just a test for the moment) I used is as follows:

```
require_once "bigcommerce-api/bigcommerce.php";

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://store-xxxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/',
'username'  => 'admin',
    'api_key'   => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$customers = Bigcommerce::getCustomers();

foreach($customers as $customer) {
    echo $customer->first_name;
echo $customer->last_name;
echo "<br/>";
}
```

My question is, how do I write the PHP code to create a new customer in my Bigcommerce store?

Thanks,

Mekong

Answer (score 1):

It's OK guys, I've got it sorted. Just my rough, test code but it works (hooray!):

```
$first_name = "Willy";
$last_name = "Wonka";
$email = "willy@wonkaville.com";
$company = "Wonka Pty Ltd";
$phone = "03 9699 1234";
$store_credit = "0";
$customer_group_id = "2";
$authentication = "harry1";

$createFields = array('first_name'=>$first_name,'last_name'=>$last_name,
'email'=>$email, 'company'=>$company,'phone'=>$phone,
'store_credit'=>$store_credit,'customer_group_id'=>$customer_group_id,
'_authentication'=>$authentication);

$customers = Bigcommerce::createCustomer($createFields);
```

Comment: However, I'm still having problems creating a password for new customer. Code (above) is not quite right regarding authentication/password. Any ideas ... anyone?